# Adding AdMob to an application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I have a lot of problems with adding ads to my application using Admob. But in the beginning I can't add Google Play Services to my project, when I do it `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'` line up highlights and all commands libGDX light up in red and don't work

In my library folder I have:

[image]

How I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to [include tags in the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 1):

Go into the SDK Manager and download the Google Player Services Package!
EDIT: [Source](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install)
[image: SDK Manager]